# Closed form expression to a nested radical formula

Tags: closed-form, nested-radicals

$$\large\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt[4]{4+\sqrt[5]{5+\sqrt[6]{6+\cdots+\sqrt[n-1]{(n-1)+{\sqrt[n]{n}}}}}}}}\right)$$

I can only obtain the numerical approximation of it:

$$2.911639216245824$$

How to find a mostly simplified cloed form expression?

Comment: I would be surprised if this had a closed form expression.  But I've been surprised before.

Comment: Try to write it as a recursion. I dont know if this is possible.